# Trying to resolve PPA issues with libvlccore9 that rendered package management inoperable

Tags: package-management, dpkg, ppa, vlc, packaging

Because PPA's don't have an actual bug tracker and they're pretty badly maintained, I figure I would just ask how to fix this here.

The package `libvlccore9` in the [vlc-master](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily) PPA is trying to install `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0` which is supposed to be installed by `libvlccore8`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libodbcinstq4-1 vlc-bin vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvlccore9
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
34 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 470 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,243 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/master-daily/ubuntu artful/main amd64 libvlccore9 amd64 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1 [470 kB]
Fetched 470 kB in 1s (279 kB/s)      
(Reading database ... 322201 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvlccore9:amd64 (3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0', which is also in package libvlccore8:amd64 3.0.0~~git20171208+r73126+99~ubuntu17.10.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

question is why is that, libvlccore8 doesn't show that file,

```
apt-file show libvlccore8
libvlccore8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.8
libvlccore8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.8.0.0
libvlccore8: /usr/share/bug/libvlccore8/control
libvlccore8: /usr/share/bug/libvlccore8/presubj
libvlccore8: /usr/share/doc/libvlccore8/NEWS.Debian.gz
libvlccore8: /usr/share/doc/libvlccore8/changelog.Debian.gz
libvlccore8: /usr/share/doc/libvlccore8/copyright
```

I have a `libvlccore8`

```
dpkg -l | grep -i libvlccore
rc  libvlccore7                                   2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1                            amd64        base library for VLC and its modules
ii  libvlccore8:amd64                             3.0.0~~git20171208+r73126+99~ubuntu17.10.1      amd64        base library for VLC and its modules
```

But I can't even remove it in the current state,

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libvlccore8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvlc5 : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 phonon4qt5-backend-vlc : Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-base : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1~) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
 vlc-plugin-notify : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1~) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
 vlc-plugin-qt : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
 vlc-plugin-samba : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1~) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
 vlc-plugin-skins2 : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1~) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
 vlc-plugin-video-output : Depends: libvlccore8 (= 3.0.0~~git20171208+r73126+99~ubuntu17.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-video-splitter : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1~) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
 vlc-plugin-visualization : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1~) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: vlc-plugin-abi-4-0-0
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And, i can't run `--fix-broken install` because then it tries to do the same thing that fails...

```
apt-get --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libodbcinstq4-1 vlc-bin vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-skins2 vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libvlccore9
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvlccore9
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
34 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/470 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,243 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 322201 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvlccore9:amd64 (3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0', which is also in package libvlccore8:amd64 3.0.0~~git20171208+r73126+99~ubuntu17.10.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171213+r73247+108~ubuntu17.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try removing all the packages that depend on `libvlccore9`, then Apt should no longer want to install it, and you can remove `libvlccore8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve these issues I ran

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0
apt-get --purge --yes remove '*vlc*'
```

This heavy handed approach eventually removed all traces of VLC. From that point, I thought I could re-add it. But then, likely the real problem all along, emerged. [The internal version strings in the PPA were borked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411518/what-is-the-root-cause-of-e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-p).

**In order to get your system into a consitent state you must manually delete `libvlccore.so.9.0.0`, without which dpkg can not proceed.**

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. Try these steps:

```
sudo dpkg --purge libvlccore8
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

Comment: Confirmed working, I only ran the first line followed by `apt-get -f install`, and upgrade completed successfully. Cheers.