# Error while installing VLC in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dpkg, dependencies, vlc

Am getting below error when trying to install VLC:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libvlc5 : Depends: libvlccore9 (>= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1~) but it is not going to be installed
vlc : Depends: vlc-bin (= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: vlc-l10n (= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: vlc-plugin-base (= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: vlc-plugin-qt (= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: vlc-plugin-video-output (= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-skins2 (= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-video-splitter (= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
      Recommends: vlc-plugin-visualization (= 3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Output of apt-get -f install:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
libvlccore9
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libvlccore9
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/472 kB of archives. After this operation, 1,247 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 359521 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvlccore9:amd64 (3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0', which is also in package libvlccore8:amd64_3.0.0~~git20171210+r73147+99~ubuntu16.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubun tu16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone please help me fix this error and install vlc

Comment: do you already have a version of vlc installed? This is the problem: `trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0', which is also in package libvlccore8:amd64`

Comment: You have very strange mixture of packages. Ordinary 16.04 LTS does not have them. Please update your post with output of `apt-cache policy libvlccore9 vlc-bin vlc-l10n vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-qt vlc-plugin-video-output`.  Do you have any PPAs or third-party repositories enabled?

Comment: same here. i'm using daily PPA and now update stucks with the same message.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem as here [Trying to resolve PPA issues with libvlccore9 that rendered package management inoperable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986350/trying-to-resolve-ppa-issues-with-libvlccore9-that-rendered-package-management-i)

IDK if it is kosher but this fixed it for me:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171215+r73271+108~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Of course because you are using 16.04 you have to do this:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_3.0.0~rc1~~git20171214+r73255+108~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Fixed identical problem with different version of libvlccore9_4.0.0~rc1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

suppress the daily build of vlc :

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-ubuntu-master-daily-xenial.list.save  
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/videolan-ubuntu-master-daily-xenial.list
```

and reinstall the official stable release :

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: that's not a fix just another solution!